# Swing initiate dragging on mouse click

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a JPanel with JList, that has dragging support enabled. Dragging works normally while holding the mouse button pressed, but I would like to initiate dragging, when the user just clicks on an item from JList and stop it, when dropping was performed.

I tried to add the MouseListener to JList, but this doesn't work (dragging is not initiated):

```
class DragListener extends MouseAdapter{
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent jlist = (JComponent) e.getSource();
        TransferHandler transferHandler = jlist.getTransferHandler();
        transferHandler.exportAsDrag(jlist, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
    }
}
```

How to initiate and keep dragging on item selection, without keeping the mouse button pressed?

Comment: I think that good described (with working code example in SSCCE/MCVE form) in Oracle DND tutorial,

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: *"How to initiate and keep dragging on item selection, without keeping the mouse button pressed?"*  Well, that's not *dragging* the list item, and the user would find it very confusing that two clicks result in a 'drag'.  So how about you **don't do that**, but instead stick to a mouse drag acting as a drag?